# GNU/screen not setting $STY

Tags: linux, shell, script, gnu-screen, sudo

I'm trying to script the spawning of GNU/screen windows by using commands of the form `screen <CMD>`.

For some reason when I start GNU/screen (by hand), the shell that it starts in window 0 (`/bin/bash`) does not contain a `$STY` environment variable. Without this commands like `screen vim` start a *nested* screen session, not another window as I want.

My environment is somewhat unusual. Here's how I end up in it:

```
ssh robm@somehost
sudo su sharedaccount
script /dev/null
screen
```

The `script /dev/null` step exists because the TTY device allocated for the `robm` user cannot be accessed by the `sharedaccount` user. The `script` command allocates a new TTY that is owned by the user that invoked it, solving that problem.

If I skip the `sudo` and `script` steps, GNU/screen sets `$STY` just fine. In other words this works just fine:

```
ssh robm@somehost
screen
```

Presumably something about `sudo` and `script` interferes with `screen`, but I'm stumped as to what.

Answer (score 2):

Gah, it was the `sharedaccount` SHELL init script's fault. It was calling `exec env -i ...` to create a new shell without cruft from the original user's environment.

Sorry if I wasted anyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could both skip the `script /dev/null` step and fix your issue if you changed your call to `su` by issuing it with a dash, like: `sudo su - sharedaccount`.
This would set all your environment variables mostly the way they would be if you'd actually logged in as `sharedaccount`.